# I can't see any invites in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I can't see any invites from **ANYONE**. Other people can, except for a friend of mine with the same problem. I can join my friends easily in the friends menu though, except for one friend who I can't join unless someone is with them in the same world. He can see my invites as well. I have tried going into the button saying 'Manage Who Can Send You Invites' but it doesn't work. I've tried going into privacy setting on Xbox.com but that doesn't work *EITHER*. Please help me with this problem, and I hope that your solution works.